# How do I disable the libpng warning? (python, pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

When I run my program it gives me the following warning:

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

I know why this is caused, the *sRGB* is what it wants, but I use *adobe photoshop RGB*.

Just wondering if there is any code to disable the warning. It doesn't affect my program. It's just annoying.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(Please don't ask me to show my code, my code has nothing to do with this situation)

Comment: For some reason it stopped happening. But I am going to keep this post open in case anyone wants to answer.

Comment: if the warning is printed in `stderr`, you may redirect it to `/dev/null` (under Linux)

Comment: If you upgraded libpng to version 1.6.12, the reason it stopped happening is that some of the warnings about incorrect sRGB profiles have been eliminated.

Comment: I did not upgrade libpng

Comment: This might help you solve the actual issue, rather than just ignoring the warning: [libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745076/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile)

Answer (score 1):

well, you can ignore the warning.
I am using ImageMagick for image resizing, and for some png file, the following code will throw exception:
iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile `' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1830

```
Blob ablob(cont.data(), cont.size()); // cont is the png file content.
Image image;
image.read(ablob);
image.resize( Geometry(100, 100) );
```

As it says, it's just a warning, you can put the image.read(ablob) in a try{}catch{} block, and ignore the exception. The object image now contains the integrated png data, and can be manipulated correctly.

Comment: Warnings don't don't raise exceptions.

Comment: The question is tagged as python, this is no python answer.

Answer (score 0):

.pyw extensions remove the console. That should do it. You can also see the source code, where it has the warning start.