# Android Gradle Project upgrading build tools to 21.0.1: aapt throws Exception

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build-tools

We have an android gradle project. Today I wanted to upgrade the android build tools version from 20 to 21.0.1, but now the aapt is failing.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':myproject-android:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        c:\_DEVELOP\AndroidSDK\sdk\build-tools\21.0.1\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I c:\_DEVELOP\AndroidSDK\sdk\platforms\android-16\android.jar -M D:\_MY_PROJECT\trunk\myproject_bin\gradle\build\re
lease\myproject-android\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S D:\_MY_PROJECT\trunk\myproject_bin\gradle\build\release\myproject-android\intermediates\res\debug -A D:\_MY_PROJECT\tr
unk\myproject_bin\gradle\build\release\myproject-android\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J D:\_MY_PROJECT\trunk\myproject_bin\gradle\build\release\myproject-android\generated\source\r\debug -F D:\_PIVOSC
ORE_P4\trunk\myproject_bin\gradle\build\release\myproject-android\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.myproject.app -0 apk --output-text-symbols D:\_MY_PROJECT\trunk\
myproject_bin\gradle\build\release\myproject-android\intermediates\symbols\debug
Error Code:
        255
```

I had some warnings saying:

```
libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
```

I fixed those, but there are 6 more in the appcompat-v7 library.

If I revert the build tools version to 20 everything works fine.

Has anyone came across this problem?

Comment: It seems this has been already reported: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77629

Comment: Be aware that there are several different but related bugs in AAPT; that bug report is kind of messy. Your error isn't the main one that was reported where it was returning error -1073741819. Please follow up, and if the bug is closed as being fixed and you're still having problems, please open a new bug.

Comment: Show your build.gradle

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is caused by a faulty `aapt`. There was a similar problem in 21.0.0 too (`Error Code: -1073741819`). You need to update `build-tools` again to fix it.

- Open SDK manager and install `build-tools 21.1.2`.
- Then change your build.gradle so that it looks like this.

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
      android {
          compileSdkVersion 21
          buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
  ```

*Replace version numbers with the most recent ones as necessary.*

Old `buildToolsVersion` 21.0.2, recommended version is 21.1.2 or later

Comment: @peter_budo Are you getting exactly the same error?

Comment: I'm getting error which @ffddani posted in his question

Comment: I am also getting same error even after updating to 21.1.1

Comment: Still there even with 21.1.2

Comment: So... what did you do to fix it @slott? My project was fine one night. The next day I open it - I get the exact error in this question. I also went to those 6 files and they're there.

Comment: I downgraded to 21 and it didn't work; went down to 20 and it works for me now! Would like to upgrade to current version of build tools. Please share if someone gets it to work.

Comment: Try adding this to your build config

 aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false

 aaptOptions {
  noCompress 'png', 'jpg'
  ignoreAssetsPattern "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:<dir>_*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
 }

Comment: There is the same issue with buildTools 22.0.0, just use 22.0.1

Comment: Still happening in 23.0.0 rc3

Comment: So what is the solution? I am getting this with 22.0.1.

Comment: Same here. Is this getting fixed at all?

Comment: Still happening in 23.0.1

Comment: Im having this problem too, someone just suggested to me that it could be because we have previously installed Phonegap on this machine and it will have its own gradle? Anyone got any more evidence of this themselves?

Comment: still in  23.0.2 also happening.

Comment: Still happening in 23.0.3

Answer (score 40):

This worked for me:

> It's metadata added by tools like Photoshop that isn't even honored by Android. Strip it.

```
brew install exiftool
find . -path '*src/main/res/*' -name '*.png' -exec exiftool -overwrite_original -all= {} \;
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/rjTQ_STR3OE/-UcNQRISTKsJ

P.S. Tested on Mac only.

Comment: The actual command (from the provided link) is `find . -path '*src/main/res/*' -name '*.png' -exec exiftool -overwrite_original -all= {} \;`  The command doesn't work without the `*` in `path`

Comment: Where should I put this lines?

Comment: terminal. 'cd' to your root project folder and paste the command.

Comment: Hi, I have try above mention command. But its not getting it. I got response that: FIND: Parameter format not correct
Please let me know how to execute it.

Comment: Im on mac and didn't work for me, I used `find ./ -name '*.png' | xargs -L 1 -I '{}' exiftool -overwrite_original -all= '{}'` instead. Thanks

Comment: For ubuntu `exiftool` is available. Install using `sudo apt-get install exiftool` and tried the find command. its working.

Comment: It also works with [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/), an online (destructive) minifier.

Answer (score 14):

Warnings about libpng are reported here but can be ignored

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77704

Project Member says the newer libpng they built against is stricter about the color profile. They will fix this in an upcoming release, but this shouldn't be an issue.

And 21.0.2 solves other issues.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745076/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile

Comment: i'm most definitely using 22.0.1 build tools and i have the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to remove the color profile from png files to avoid this warning by using pngcrush [Wikipedia about pngcrush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush).

If you are working on MacOS you can also use a tool called [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/) to run pngcrush and replace the stripped .png files on the fly.

Comment: ater installing it (`apt-get install pngcrush` on ubuntu) you can run it like this: `find . -path '*src/main/res /*' -name '*.png' -exec bash -c 'pngcrush $0 ${0}' {} \;`

Answer (score 2):

21.0.1 breaks my project as well - aapt will not add any string resource to the APK.
Reverted back to 20.0.0, by editing *project.config*:

```
sdk.buildtools=20.0.0
```

Comment: What problem or error were you having? It works perfectly fine.

Comment: PackageManager crashes upon not finding the string resource for the app name. Aapt d strings shows no strings at all in the APK.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with build tools 21.0.0, but after updating to 21.0.1 it has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason it is not practical to manually strip the meta data from the files you can disable the use of the new and more strict png crusher by setting the following in your build.gradle.

```
aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same warnings and aapt was getting stuck even with build tools 22.0.1.I ticked the option Compile independent modules in parallel in settings>compiler which resulted in more than one instance of aapt running and build was successful.

Answer (score -4):

remove the `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:xxx` dependency