# libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

Tags: titanium-mobile

I am trying to change the color of the cursor in TextField in Titanium android app.
For that I created `platform/android/res/values/` folder.

I placed the following code in `tiapp.xml`:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <manifest>
    <application android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium">
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="22" android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>
  </manifest>
</android>
```

When I am trying to run the app, getting the following error. 
I am working on 3.4.1. API Level is 22 only.

```
[ERROR] :  Failed to package application:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_light.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ab_share_pack_holo_light.9.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_clear_disabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_clear_disabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ic_clear_disabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_ic_clear_disabled.png: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'GRAY': Gray color space not permitted on RGB PNG
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_clear_normal.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_ic_clear_normal.png: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'GRAY': Gray color space not permitted on RGB PNG
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_go.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_go.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ic_go.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_ic_go.png: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'GRAY': Gray color space not permitted on RGB PNG
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ic_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_ic_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'GRAY': Gray color space not permitted on RGB PNG
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-mdpi/abc_ic_voice_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-hdpi/abc_ic_voice_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_ic_voice_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
[ERROR] :  /var/folders/7f/5k6k5fvn2fdc5bgtv3hjmgnh0000gn/T/11558-48051-1806d86/res/drawable-xxhdpi/abc_ic_voice_search.png: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 'GRAY': Gray color space not permitted on RGB PNG
[ERROR] :  /Users/murali/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/textboxapp/build/android/res/values/styles.xml:3: error: A 'type' attribute is required for <item>
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1.
```

Comment: This should be helpful: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446610/android-gradle-project-upgrading-build-tools-to-21-0-1-aapt-throws-exception][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446610/android-gradle-project-upgrading-build-tools-to-21-0-1-aapt-throws-exception

Answer (score 13):

As the warnings say, you have a bunch of PNG files with invalid color profiles.  Libpng16 issues warnings about them.  Your application treats warnings as errors.

To work around this, you can do one or more of the following:

- Use a PNG editor to remove the iCCP chunk from the PNG files listed
  in the error report, e.g., with ImageMagick's "convert -define
  png:exclude-chunk=iCCP,zCCP"
- Use a PNG editor to remove all ancillary chunks, e.g., convert -strip
- Downgrade your libpng to version 1.5.x (currently libpng-1.5.23)
- Reinstall libpng-1.6.x (currently libpng-1.6.17) with "-DPNG_sRGB_PROFILE_CHECKS=-1"
- Find out if there is a way to have your application treat warnings as warnings, not errors, and do that.