# Migrating Eclipse project to android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, aapt, migrating

Migrating Project from eclipse to studio getting aapt error

I already refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30710304/3514144) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31497159/3514144) but don't get idea how can i resolve it

```
 AAPT err(Facade for 581583437): D:\Ajay\Convert xyzTo Studio\Studio\xyz\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_bookmark.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

AAPT err(Facade for 581583437): D:\Ajay\Convert xyzTo Studio\Studio\xyz\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_like.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 822066601): D:\Ajay\Convert xyzTo Studio\Studio\xyz\src\main\res\drawable-large-mdpi\ic_rate.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 822066601): D:\Ajay\Convert xyzTo Studio\Studio\xyz\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_logout.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 822066601): D:\Ajay\Convert xyzTo Studio\Studio\xyz\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_dashboard.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 822066601): D:\Ajay\Convert xyzTo Studio\Studio\xyz\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi\ic_question_radio.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 822066601): D:\Ajay\Convert xyzTo Studio\Studio\xyz\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_inbox.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 822066601): D:\Ajay\Convert xyzTo Studio\Studio\xyz\src\main\res\drawable-large-mdpi\ic_user.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
AAPT err(Facade for 822066601): D:\Ajay\Convert xyzTo Studio\Studio\xyz\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_logout.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
```

Comment: Maybe this article can help you [Migrating from Eclipse ADT](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

Comment: Your PNG files are bad. Those links pretty clearly tell you how to fix it

Comment: but how png is bad? i'm already using this png in eclipse how can i fix it those png?does it require new ?@cricket_007

Comment: @FilipeManuel yes i'm following this link for convert project into eclipse but after finish all steps it showing me above error and missing my Resource R.file while project is running in eclipse fine

Comment: does my drawables png extension creates problem?should i have to change png to jpg?

Comment: Try to `Build -> Rebuild project`.