# Can't generate signed apk from Android Studio “Execution failed for task ':packageRelease'” when using JodaTime in some classes

Tags: android, gradle, android-proguard

I am using Android Studio 1.2.2 and tried to generate APK with proguard setting. Also I am using **joda-time-2.7.jar** in my app.

This brings me following error message.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> Unable to compute hash of D:\Voice\app\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar

Here is **gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.xxxwew.voice"
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 23
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
   }
   buildTypes {
      release {
         minifyEnabled true
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
  }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
   compile files('libs/joda-time-2.7.jar')
}
```

Here is some important things in **Messages in Gradle Build**

```
Warning:org.joda.time.DateMidnight: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.DateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.DateTimeZone: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Days: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.DateTimeZone: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Days: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Duration: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Hours: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Hours: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Instant: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDate: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDate: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.LocalTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Minutes: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Minutes: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.MonthDay: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.MonthDay: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Months: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Months: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.MutableDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.MutablePeriod: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Period: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Seconds: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Seconds: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Weeks: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Weeks: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.YearMonth: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.YearMonth: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.Years: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
Warning:org.joda.time.Years: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractDuration: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractInstant: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:org.joda.time.base.AbstractPeriod: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
Warning:there were 37 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
     You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
     If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
     the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
            (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:473)
  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:233)
  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:98)
  at proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask.proguard(ProGuardTask.java:1074)
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask.doMinification(AndroidProGuardTask.java:139)
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidProGuardTask$1.run(AndroidProGuardTask.java:115)
  at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:48)
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
  at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:227)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Have you any ideas about this.

Thank you.

Comment: call this `compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.3'`  instead of `compile files('libs/joda-time-2.7.jar')`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : Your suggestion brings me this ,                             Error:Failed to resolve: joda-time:joda-time-2.7:
<a href="openFile:D:/AndroidStudioProjects/VoiceType/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: Clean-Rebuild & sync(gradle ) your project

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : Then this brings me following error messages ,                     Like following ,                       AAPT err(837950010): D:\AndroidStudioProjects\VoiceType\app\src\main\res\drawable\recycle_bin.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited .

Comment: That is another case .problem for your `recycle_bin.png` image

Comment: Hope two links helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709056/libpng-warning-iccp-not-recognizing-known-srgb-profile-that-has-been-edited

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495147/android-studio-libpng-warning-iccp-not-recognizing-known-srgb-profile-that-h

Comment: let me inform please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a answer to this problem.

Should add following lines to pro-guard file:

```
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-keep class org.joda.time.** { *; }
-keep interface org.joda.time.** { *;}
```

I would like thank [Exaqt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2429753/exaqt) for the help.