# Build Fails on Each Run

Tags: android, android-build

I have already installed Android SDK Platform 19

Warning:Project is building density based multiple APKs but using tools version 19, you should upgrade to build-tools 21 or above to ensure proper packaging of resources.

:app:processDebugResources FAILED

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/sneha/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: May be this 'll help check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446610/android-gradle-project-upgrading-build-tools-to-21-0-1-aapt-throws-exception). Update your build tools version to latest and try.