# iccp:Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

Tags: android, xamarin, cross-platform, srgb

The following warning keeps arising in my Xamarin cross platform PCL project:

> iccp:Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

What should I do ?

Comment: I've the same issue since installed Xamarin.Android.Support.v7 (v21) from nuget. Try installing a previous version (v20), it may help.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem on a Xamarin Android project using Xamarin.Forms.Maps. I tried different version of the Support lib with the same result. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745076/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile)

Comment: I followed this tutorial - [Get Rid of – iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited](http://www.laurivan.com/get-rid-iccp-not-recognizing-known-srgb-profile-has-been-edited/).

Comment: rebuild project worked for me

Answer (score 22):

If you have image magick installed
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php

find . -name "*.png" -print -exec convert "{}" "{}" ";"

cleaned up the files, and made them smaller in the process.

Comment: Do you plug it in just like that? Like say my file's name is "image" Would I plug into terminal (after download imagemagick) "image.png"-print-exec convert "{}""{}"";" just like that? Or is there more to be done? (Forgive my noob-i-ness)

Comment: the command `find . -name "*.png" -print -exec convert "{}" "{}" ";"` does on the whole folder plus sub-folders what `convert image.png image.png` would do on just `image.png`. `find` finds stuff with `-name` = `*.png`, `-print`s it and `-exec`utes the command `convert` with its findings (`{}`) as parameter twice.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with Android studio. Just clean the project and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

I found a workaround that may help.

I downloaded the ImageOptim software: https://imageoptim.com/ (Free)

and went to the folder Xamarin/Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/21.0.3/embedded and drag the images into the imageoptim and it deleted the metada.

And that fixed.

Answer (score 4):

This warning is due to the unwanted bytes or metadata in the image file.
It is mostly arises due to the update of libpng inside of the Android SDK.

Try these tools to delete metadata from corresponding images :

[ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/)

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

[Trimage](http://trimage.org/)

Answer (score 2):

had the same problem. trying to remove and re-add the same images showed in the console that **another** file had an invalid name (with "-" in the name). Fixing the other file's name, solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since most answers are for Linux here is a windows solution:

Download ImageMagick and run the folloing command in cmd:

```
magick mogrify -format png *.png
```

and it will convert all png in the folder you are in into png without the problems.

Answer (score 0):

What solved my problem is to remove the doubted one image(Which is large in size & it's been store in all Drawable folders of my app module.)

I have tried by Changing **build tools** , **removing AppCompat lib**.

Also Check that whether any of your image is not opening in ***Android Editor*** by double clicking on the Image from **drawable folder**.

If this load problem occurs, It means you have to remove this image from all folders and try by **ReAdding** it after **Renaming** the same image.

Or there's is an accepted answers available if it can help you.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/31497159

Which will help you Optimize your image in all neccessary manner.