# libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile Android

Tags: android

While runnig my avd in android studio 2.0 it is giving error libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile . Can anyone help me on this . I dont understand this error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: "libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495147/android-studio-libpng-warning-iccp-not-recognizing-known-srgb-profile-that-h)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495147/android-studio-libpng-warning-iccp-not-recognizing-known-srgb-profile-that-h?rq=1 (The error message is different but the cause and solutions are essentially the same).

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson, that question seems to be about a bad PNG file in the Android Studio project, whereas this question is about a warning emitted by the Android Studio emulator itself.

Comment: The libpng16 decoder is complaining about a bad input file.  It doesn't matter whether it came from somewhere else or was generated by your app; it contains an old profile (probably from Microsoft/HP) that needs to be updated.