# how to solve AAPT err

Tags: android, gradle, aapt

When building android project, I meet following problem:[image]

Comment: Question is already asked..

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31497159/5733111)

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem, Android Studio prompts in bottom window pane should do this for you but if you can't figure it out, do it manually by changing build tools in gradle to this:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-beta3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your buildtools to the lastest such as `23.0.2`.

You can edit it in your `build.gradle` file like this:

```
android {
...
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
...
}
```

hope it works for you.