# Image distortion when imshow in opencv

Tags: opencv, imshow

I download the "Acp.png" picture from the internet, and I want to turn it to gray picture. But when I try to imshow it, the picture distorted, and **there is a warning showing that"iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile"**. I just don't know why, who can help explain it? Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGUvz.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745076/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile)

Comment: Thank you, but my code is in OpenCV, it seems not the same situation. And I can't understand.