# In GNU Octave, how to solve libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

Tags: octave, libpng

I am doing math using GNU Octave, but no matter what version of GNU Octave I install, this warning appears every time I want to plot something, and then the program has no response.

`libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited`

My question has nothing to do with Android Studio.
I know it is not the problem of GNU Octave, but I do not know how to fix.

OS: Windows 8.1 x64

GNU Octave 4.2.0 installed by octave-4.2.0-w64-installer

[this is the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUtYl.png)

Comment: what OS and how have you installed which GNU Octave version? I know some of these can be answered from the linked screenshot but it should be in your question as TEXT

Comment: OK. I installed GNU Octave 4.2.0 on Windows 8.1 x64 by  octave-4.2.0-w64-installer.

Answer (score 0):

All these warnings can be removed by using a command tool called "pngcrush" in git bash on Windows. And then Octave will work well.

[follow this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29337595/7110228)