# How to reshape png image read by skimage.imread

Tags: python, image, png, scikit-image, opencv

Then I read some jpg file, this way

```
image = imread('aa.jpg')
```

As result I get dataframe with numbers from 1 to 255

I can resize it this way:

```
from cv2 import resize
image = resize(image, (256, 256)
```

But then I doing same think with png, result not desired.

```
image = imread('aa2.png')  # array with number within 0-1 range
resize(image, (256,256)) # returns 1 channel image
resize(image, (256,256, 3))   # returns 3 channel image
```

Weird image
[image]

But `imshow(image)`

[image]

Comment: You are looking for `skimage.transform.resize` or `skimage.transform.rescale`.

Comment: Please include your `import` statements so it is clear which modules you are using and your example is Minimal and Complete. Please also include your `aa.png` image. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv2.imread` reads the image in 3 channel by default instead of 4. Pass the parameter `cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` to read your PNG file and then try to resize it as shown in the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('Snip20190412_12.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print(img.shape) #(215, 215, 4)

height, width = img.shape[:2]
res = cv.resize(img,(2*width, 2*height))
print(res.shape)#(430, 430, 4)
plt.imshow(res)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess is some problem with your image or code.

Here a free image to try: https://pixabay.com/vectors/copyright-free-creative-commons-98566/

Maybe you have problem with libpng, check this answers: [libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745076/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile)

Check this simple code that works on PNG images.

```
     import cv2 as cv
     image = cv.imread("foto.png")
     if __name__ == "__main__":
          while True:
                image = cv.resize(image,(200,200))
                cv.imshow("prueba",image)

                key = cv.waitKey(10)
                if key == 27:
                    cv.destroyAllWindows()
                    break   

     cv.destroyAllWindows()
```