# Error occurred while starting the kernel in Ursina

Tags: python, ursina

I just trying run ursina but when I run it I get this error:

```
An error ocurred while starting the kernel 
Known pipe types: 
wglGraphicsPipe 
(3 aux display modules not yet loaded.) 
:display:windisplay(warning): SetForegroundWindow() failed! 
:pnmimage:png(warning): iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

Does anybody know the solution?
I am using Windows 11, spyder(python editor).
My program creates an window and when I try to close it program crash.

Code:

```
import ursina

app = ursina.Ursina()
app.run()
```

Comment: Could you please enter the error as text instead of as an image?

Comment: An error ocurred while starting the kernel
Known pipe types:
wglGraphicsPipe
(3 aux display modules not yet loaded.)
:display:windisplay(warning): SetForegroundWindow() failed!
:pnmimage:png(warning): iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

Comment: Is that the complete output you get? also, does your program crash or run?

Comment: You should add information about your system. Which OS, Python, hardware, etc.

Comment: Ok,  I am using Windows 10, spyder(python editor)

Comment: Can you please provide some more code because it seems to be a problem with a png image? Does this code works `app = Ursina(); app.run()` or when you have some more code it doesn't? It seems to be a problem with some kind of texture or image. I recommend checking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745076/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile

Comment: @Lixt so I don't added any code in my question because all my code is three lines: `import ursina

app = ursina.Ursina()
app.run()`

Comment: How did you install Ursina and panda3d?

Comment: @Lixt with `pip`

Comment: I think you should join Ursina Discord Server and ask @Pokepetter what is happening and the why and then post the answer here. Otherwise I have no clue what that may be.