# libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile in .NET Core

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, rgb, libpng

We have `.NET Core` application which is hosted under Linux based Docker container. `System.Drawing` library wasn't working here so we needed to installed `libpng` with command `apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libgdiplus libc6-dev`.

It sorted out image problem but we can see lots of warnings in CloudWatch like `libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile`. We also tried to set LogLevel `"System.Drawing": "Error"` but no luck.

Is there any way we can completely avoid this messages?

Comment: I believe this can happen if png assigns an srgb profile to a black/white  or grayscale image.

Comment: @fmw42 The user can upload any file their own so this is not under our control.

Comment: My comment was not meant as a fix, but only a possible explanation for why you get the message..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced all `Image` process related code from `System.Drawing` library to `MagickImage` and so now, I don't need `libpng`.

Answer (score 0):

Libpng-1.6 onwards is stricter in checking ICC profiles than previous versions. This warning is printed every time a broken png is found. This warning can be ignored and fixes will include:

```
1.Downgrade to an older version of libpng
2.Install imagemagick and use convert -strip to convert all .png files (script below)
```

A script that will change all .png files in the current directory:

```
for f in $(find . -type f -name "*.png")
do
echo "Processing $f ..."
convert $f -strip $f
done
```

More can refer to this post:

[libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745076/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile)