# Ursina game engine message: Known incorrect sRGB profile

Tags: python, ursina

I am trying to learn how to use Ursina engine for python, and everything seems to work alright when I'm loading up a sample project from their github, but every time I run it
I get the following:

```
C:\Users\notrealnamecauseprivacy\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/notrealnamecauseprivacy/PycharmProjects/pythonProject6/main.py
package_folder: C:\Users\notrealnamecauseprivacy\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\venv\lib\site-packages\ursina
asset_folder: C:\Users\notrealnamecauseprivacy\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6
screen resolution: (1920, 1080)
Known pipe types:
  wglGraphicsPipe
(3 aux display modules not yet loaded.)
:pnmimage:png(warning): iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
:pnmimage:png(warning): iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
info: development mode: True
application successfully started
info: changed aspect ratio: 1.778 -> 1.778

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Everything works as it should, but anything red appearing in my terminal worries me. Should I be concerned? And, if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: If you're making your own artwork, this probably isn't worrying about unless you have a color-calibrated display; if your own display isn't calibrated, you already have a random/unknown level of error thrown in between what you see on your screen and what a user/customer with a well-calibrated display will see on theirs, so you've got bigger things to worry about than the metadata.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43415650/14122 in particular does a lot of good towards explaining what's going on here. The D50 whitepoint is a lot redder than what you'll see on a modern computer or HDTV display (which tend higher / more blue). I don't particularly agree with the answers that suggest throwing out the metadata -- ideally, you'd have a color profile embedded, but one that's actually fit-to-purpose.