CURL - Sending PDF failing with Laravel
I'm sending a PDF file via CURL in Laravel:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\EmailSender;


use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class EmailAttachments  extends Mailable{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    function __construct($from, $to, $subject, $description, $attachments, $file_names = null){
        if(str_contains($to, 'email.com')){
            return;
        }

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/'.config('app.mailgun_domain').'/messages');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: multipart/form-data'));

        $post = array(
            'from' => $from,
            'to' => $to,
            'subject' => $subject,
            'text'    => 'Your mail do not support HTML',
            'html' => $description
        );
        
        // Attach all my files
        // Note that this files are with the full path, since the public_path to the file
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            echo $attachment;
            $post['attachment[' . $i . ']'] = curl_file_create($attachment, null, $file_names == null ? 'Report_' . date('W') .'.pdf' : $file_names[$i]);
            $i++;
        }  
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api' . ':' . config('app.mailgun_secret'));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}


?>


And I'm getting this message:
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
Error:operation aborted by callback

I am doing the same way in other project and its working.
I checked the files and the paths are ok. I double checked. The path is ok and the extension file is ".pdf".
Example:
/home/root/backend.app.com/storage/app\works\obras\Report_0.pdf

The file is created and ready to be attached.
I searched for solutions but all the topics are talking about PNG and other formats. And I didn't find the solution.
I tried to update Curl but still no success.

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745076/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile ? The question is about PNG files but there seems to be over lap with the PDF issue.

Which line specifically is giving you the "libpng warning"? Is it echo $attachment;? If so, is it possible that some command is generated a PDF but failing and returning an error message, and you are seeing it here?

Maybe the answers is stupid and the problem also was.
I will let the solution to my problem.
When defining the path to the attachments I used // backslashes.
For example:
"path//" . $variable . "//other_folder//a.pdf"

But I should be doing as:
"path/" . $variable . "other_folder/a.pdf"


It seems he doesn't like the double backslashes. Funny, it was working locally. But on the server it was not working
